# Grails Facebook Authentication plugin error after redirect

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, facebook-authentication

I am using [Facebook Authentication plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) (0.17) for Spring Security (2.0-RC5).

I've included everything that is asked there, plus followed the example to create my service to get logged in user data (from Facebook).
In the [example app FacebookAuthService](https://github.com/splix/grails-facebook-authentication-example/tree/master/grails-app/services/FacebookAuthService.groovy) (that I've fully copied to my app) there is a "FacebookUser create()" function. 
After connecting with Facebook and redirecting back to my application (with stac turned on) I get :

```
    | Error 2015-07-07 12:55:47,567 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR [/bicycles-new].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/bicycles-new] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
Message: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
    Line | Method
->>  366 | run                   in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run                   in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass             in java.lang.ClassLoader
|     52 | create . . . . . . .  in FacebookAuthService
|    113 | create                in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao
|     72 | authenticate . . . .  in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider
|     58 | attemptAuthentication in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthRedirectFilter
|     46 | doFilter . . . . . .  in     ''
|     62 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

The code line is

`Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)`

Error is thrown when creating the object.
I'd appreciate any clue of what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: will be helpful to see more detailed stacktrace. try to run app with `--stacktrace` option

Comment: I've edited my question - now error is with stacktrace

Comment: I guess you need to add Apache HttpClient to your classpath

Comment: Good guess. I added compile `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5'` to dependencies in my BuildConfig.groovy. Works like a charm! Could You make it as an answer, so I can accept it, Igor? And big thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Apache HttpClient to your dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```